# Hibernate ignores @Table(name = "...") for extended classes - created tablenames are all lower case

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

We create our tables automaticly via Hibernate by assigning:

```
@Table(name = "some_table")
```

That used to work for "normal" entities. But when we have an abstract base class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class PersonBankAccount extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
```

that is extended by

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_bank_account")
public class PersonBankAccountSimple extends PersonBankAccount {
```

The resulting table in the database is named

```
personbankaccount
```

What is going on here?

The autogenerator says:

```
table not found: PersonBankAccount
```

when first creating it and on rerun he says:

```
table found: personbankaccount
```

Like I said, for normal tables everything works fine.

Comment: Not sure if its relevant or not, but you need to specify the discriminator column and value when using single table inheritance strategy.

Comment: @Perception I don't think that you **must** provide discriminator column. JPA 2.0 FR spec says (11.1.10 "DiscriminatorColumn Annotation"): *"If the DiscriminatorColumn annotation is missing, and a discriminator column is required, the name of the discriminator column defaults to "DTYPE" and the discriminator type to STRING."*

Comment: Yeah, he does that automatically. Was wondering where those DTYPE columns came from.. ;) Can I actually disable those columns, if I always have exactly one extending class in every target application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't be the name of table in the base class instead.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "person_bank_account")
public class PersonBankAccount extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
```

Comment: I think I tried that, it didn't work and probably is only for the Joined Table inheritance. But I'll give it another shot, see what happens. Maybe also with having a table name in both classes.. The thing is, everything is working well with that setup, application logic and all, just the names are weird..

Comment: Looks like it worked out, though I wonder why I decided to put the table name in the extended class. Must have had a reason that is escaping now me because it seems natural and logical to put the name in the base class.. Oh well, thanks anyway ;)