# Hibernate won't let me use entity class name for table name

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity named `LocationType` (`BaseEntity` is a `@MappedSuperclass`):

```
@Entity
public class LocationType extends BaseEntity
```

The table name generated for this entity is `location_type`. I understand the default naming strategy works like this.

What I cannot understand is why I cannot force Hibernate to use literal name, `locationtype`. No matter what I do:

```
@Entity(name = "LocationType")
public class LocationType
```

or

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LocationType")
public class LocationType
```

or

```
@Entity(name = "LocationType")
@Table(name = "LocationType")
public class LocationType
```

the table name **always** ends up as `location_type`. Hibernate just knows better!

If I use any other name

```
@Entity(name = "wtf")
```

then table name becomes `wtf` as well.

Is this documented behaviour? Looks like a bug to me.

Similar question: [Hibernate ignores @Table(name = "...") for extended classes - created tablenames are all lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8605566/838434) (it refers to inheritance mapping, though).

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using? Also are you using hibernate annotations or javax.persistence annotations?

Comment: I don't see any issue if I use `javax.persistence.Entity`, can you post some more details like any specific properties in hibernate.cfg.xml file and your super class etc to understand the issue beter.

Comment: Both @Entity and @Table are from ``javax.persistence``. Hibernate version is 4.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed strange to me that Hibernate does not obey what is specified in the `@Table(name="...")` annnotation, so I dug up this bug report, 9 years old as of now:

[NamingStrategy should not be used when table or column name is supplied](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-318)

The bug was rejected, God and Gavin King know why (or maybe it's just God now). This contradicts JPA 1/2 specifications. The final answer, thus is: it's just how Hibernate works out of the box; if you hold your annotation names dear (or JPA compliance), you should implement your own naming strategy to fix this quirk.

Answer (score 3):

have a look here in docs.

[ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html)

[Implementing a NamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy).

It is the behavior of the `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy` , which will convert the mixed case names to the embedded underscores name . http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html . So if you explicitly use the name "EventLog" , it will convert to the "event_log" .

If you simply want to use the name explicitly specified in the `@Table` , you should use the `org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy` . By default it is used when you instantiate your `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` object

If you would like to use the `ImprovedNamingStrategy` for all tables except those which specify a name explicitly you can use the subclass below. The columnName and tableName methods are the ones called when a name is explicitly specified, this subclass leaves the specified names unmolested.

```
public class RespectfulImprovedNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy
{
    @Override
    public String columnName(String columnName)
    {
        return columnName;
    }

    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName)
    {
        return tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public String classToTableName(String className) {
    return addUnderscores( StringHelper.unqualify(className) );
    }
}
```

more links to refer.

[link1](http://anujhibernate.blogspot.in/2012/10/implementing-naming-convention.html)

[link2](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/)

Comment: In what way is it related to the impossibility of overriding the naming strategy with an explicit name given in the annotation, as described in the question?